# Android Eclipse ddms thread view perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

Need help here with the Thread view perspective of Eclipse..

For some reason when I select particular thread in Thread view, the details of the thread are not seen  (below Refresh button)

The class name gets cut off and file/method name columns are not seen...
I have tried changing the ddms view settings but in vain!!

Any help here would be really appreciated!...!

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue and as a workaround select the content in the window then paste it in notepad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Well in my case I would like to get the File and Method columns as well...Selecting the content and pasting it in notepad doesn't help much!!